# How to find a vector perpendicular to $a$ and $b$?

Tags: vectors

if $a=7i-2j-5k$ and $b=5i+j+3k$, find a vector perpendicular to $a$ and $b$. Can anyone explain how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: what are the properties of cross product?

Comment: Are you familiar with the cross product?

Answer (score 3):

Method $1$:

Cross product

Method $2$:

Suppose vector $c$ is perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$, then $a\cdot c=0$ and $b\cdot c=0$.

Solve for $$7x_1-2x_2-5x_3=0$$
$$5x_1+x_2+x_3=0$$

Comment: +1.  Maybe use "\cdot" for the dot product, though?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary vector $C=c_1\hat{i}+c_2\hat{j}+c_3\hat{j}$ perpendicular to $A=a_1\hat{i}+a_2\hat{j}+a_3\hat{j}$ and $B=b_1\hat{i}+b_2\hat{j}+b_3\hat{j}$ satisfies :
$$A . C=a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3=0$$ and
$$B . C=b_1c_1+b_2c_2+b_3c_3=0.$$
Solve for ${c_1,c_2,c_3}$. Note you get a continuous family of vectors.